# Creating a view which references the most recent version of a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a view that will point to the most recent version of a table. For instance, if there are two tables, tblZipCode2014 and tblZipCode2013, I would want the view to return everything in tblZipCode2014. Then, if a new table called tblZipCode2015 is created the view would return everything in tblZipCode2015. This way a user could always use the view to get the current Zip Code information.

The following code should get the most recent table name, but I can't figure out how to get the view to reference this table dynamically.

> `SELECT name
>   FROM ( SELECT name,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name desc) AS RowNum
>          FROM Geospatial.sys.tables 
>          WHERE name like 'tblZipCode____') AS x 
>   WHERE RowNum = 1`

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You will need dynamic SQL for this and view can only have a simple single select statement in its definition. Stored procedure seems to me the only option for you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you storing similar data in multiple tables?

You should have one table `tblZipCode` that has a column for the year.  Then you could just do:

```
create view v_tblZipCode
    select *
    from tblZipCode
    where year = (select max(year) from tblZipcode);
```

(The subquery would actually be fast using an index.)

But, to be honest, you can solve your particular problem by defining a view or synonym in a regularly scheduled job.  This job would use dynamic SQL to get the most recent table and then define the view for the users.

I think something like this would work:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

select top 1 @sql = 'create view myview as select * from sys.' + table_name
from information_schema.tables t
where table_name like 'tblZipCode____' and schema_name = 'sys'
order by table_name desc;

exec(@sql);
```

Just put this in a regularly scheduled job, and the most recent table will get used.

Comment: +1 for "Why are you storing similar data in multiple tables?"

Comment: I have multiple tables with similar information because I'm unsure whether newer versions of the table will have additional columns, and I want to allow for that to happen. I think your answer would work perfectly, but I don't handle scheduled jobs and I don't want to cause too much work for others. I'm probably going to end up adding some code to the batch file which imports the ZipCode tables into sql to alter the view so that it refers to the current ZipCode table. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible to do in a view.  You cannot make a table name dynamic in a select statement unless you are using dynamic sql and you cannot use dynamic SQL in a view, because you cannot use the exec command.

You might try something like this instead:

- Create a table called tblZipCodeCurrent (create a synonym or view to change the name to something users would prefer)
- When you are adding a new table, change the name of the old one to have the year and add the new one as tblZipCodeCurrent

Answer (score 0):

Create a view using a union all statement like so:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vwZipCode
AS 
SELECT zip_year, state_code, zip_code, area_code, county_FIPS, county_name, preferred, zip_code_type
FROM (
    SELECT 2010 AS zip_year, state_code, zip_code, area_code, county_FIPS, county_name, preferred, zip_code_type
    FROM dbo.tblZipCode2010
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2011 AS zip_year, state_code, zip_code, area_code, county_FIPS, county_name, preferred, zip_code_type
    FROM dbo.tblZipCode2010
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2012 AS zip_year, state_code, zip_code, area_code, county_FIPS, county_name, preferred, zip_code_type
    FROM dbo.tblZipCode2010
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2013 AS zip_year, state_code, zip_code, area_code, county_FIPS, county_name, preferred, zip_code_type
    FROM dbo.tblZipCode2010
    ...
) x
WHERE zip_year = YEAR(GETDATE())
```

Carry it out as far in advance as you like.

That being said, the synonym solution mentioned in another answer is your better choice.